# Unable to create a java regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to build a regex that can match:

```
VAR1="custom_var%GHsadsd.%GHsadd%Gasd.var%Grandom"
```

for VAR1=", I am using `VAR[0-9]+="`

The string in double quotes can accept all possible characters.
Regex will only fail if a substring starting with "%GH" didn't end with a dot.
Example:

```
VAR1="custom_var%GHsadsd.%GHsadd%Ga"   --> FAIL
VAR1="%GHasdas"                        --> FAIL
VAR1="%GHasdas.random"                 --> PASS
VAR1="custom"                          --> PASS
VAR1="custom%."                        --> PASS              
VAR1="custom%Grandom"                  --> PASS
```

It's my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I hope I have not violated something.

I would really appreciate if you can explain me the solution too. I am new to regex and kind of spent the whole weekend on this and lost all the hope.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to match. Can you be more specific? Do you need to match everything between `"..."`?

Comment: Yes, I need to match everything in "...".

Comment: `VAR1="custom_var%GHsadsd.%GHsadd%Ga"` In this, if we add a `.` at the end, should it be a match then? `VAR1="custom_var%GHsadsd.%GHsadd%Ga."` Should this pass or fail?

Comment: VAR1="custom_var%GHsadsd.%GHsadd%Ga." should pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```
^(VAR[0-9]+)="((%GH[^".]+\.)|(([^"%]|%(?!GH))+))+"$
```

You can try and read a break out here https://regex101.com/r/904FYc/1

`(VAR[0-9]+)` matches the left part with the var number as you already know

Then, within the `"` double-quotes, `(...|...)+` matches any number of groups composed in 2 possible manners:

1. `(%GH[^".]+\.)` matches a group starting with `%GH`, ending with a `.` dot, and not containing any dots or double-quotes inbetween (`[^".]`)
2. `(([^"%]|%(?!GH))+)` is in turn composed of 2 possible matches separated with a `|` (or), that can be repeated any number of times (due to the `+`):

   - `[^"%]` matches any non-double-quote, non-percent character
   - `%(?!GH)` matches a `%` percent symbol, not followed by the string `GH` (using a negative lookahead)

As you asked for a Java regex, here's the escaped pattern for Java:

```java
Pattern.compile("^(VAR[0-9]+)=\"((%GH[^\".]+\\.)|(([^\"%]|%(?!GH))+))+\"$");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a pattern to match all between double quotes, or match `%GH` followed by a `.` and assert no more occurrences of `%GH` at the right before the closing `"`

```
^VAR[0-9]+="(?:(?![^"]*%GH)[^"]+|[^"]*%GH[^".]*\.(?![^"]*%GH)[^"]*)"$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `VAR[0-9]+=` Match `VAR` 1+ digits and `=`
- `"` Match opening `"`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?![^"]*%GH)` Negative lookahead, assert no occurrence of `%GH` before matching a `"`
  - `[^"]+` If that is the case, match 1+ chars other than `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^"]*%GH` Match optional chars other than `%GH`, then match `%GH`
  - `[^".]*\.` Match optional chars except a `.`, then match a `.`
  - `(?![^"]*%GH)[^"]*` At this point, assert no more occurrences of `%GH` to the right (not matching a ")
- `)` Close non capture group
- `"` Match closing `"`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ACVYsY/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tU1wyH)

In Java with the doubled escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "^VAR[0-9]+=\"(?:(?![^\"]*%GH)[^\"]+|[^\"]*%GH[^\".]*\\.(?![^\"]*%GH)[^\"]*)\"$";
```